# Return Nil for Generic Type

Tags: ios, generics, swift2

I have the following code:

```
class Function<T> {
    var ptr: () throws -> T

    init<Func>(block: Func, args: AnyObject...) {
        self.ptr = {() throws -> T in
            let result: AnyObject? = nil

            if T.self == Void.self {
                return Void() as! T
            }

            return result //Error Here.. Cannot as! cast it either.. Cannot unsafeBitCast it either..
        }
    }
}

postfix operator ^ { }
postfix func ^ <T>(left: Function<T>) throws -> T {
    return try left.ptr()
}


func call() {
    let block: (String) -> String? = {(arg) -> String? in
        return nil
    }

    let fun = Function<String?>(block: block, args: "Hello")
    fun^
}
```

The function `Block.execute` returns `AnyObject?`. My Generic class `Function<T>` expects a return type of `T`.

If `T` is already `String?` why can't I return nil?

Is there any way to return nil as type T which is already Optional?

If I make `T` Optional, then the return type becomes `Optional<Optional<String>>` which is not what I want.. then the compiler complains that `OptionalOptional` is not unwrapped with `??` That is how I know that `T` is already optional.

Comment: From where is this `execute` method coming?

Comment: From internal library. It always returns 'AnyObject?'

Comment: Try to make examples that can be easily reproduced, like copy-pasted into a playground.

Comment: All I asked was how can I return nil from a generic. The above can literally be copy pasted. You can play with it and set result to nil if you like. It's any object. The question is clear. You cannot return nil to a generic type that is NOT optional. You can do this for any generic. Not just my code.

Comment: In either case, I've updated the question with a paste-able example. There are no answers and probably won't be.

Comment: When i try this in both Swift2 and Swift3 the `return result as! T` cast seems to work properly.

Comment: The as! Cast will force unwrap nil to convert it to type T. In that case, it fails because attempt to unwrap nil optional according to the compiler/runtime.

Answer (score 2):

After a long hunt on google I have finally found an elegant way to do this. It's possible to write a class extension with type constraints.

```
class Foo<T> {
  func bar() -> T {
    return something
    // Even if T was optional, swift does not allow us to return nil here:
    // 'nil' is incompatible with return type 'T'
  }

}
```

```
extension Foo where T: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    func bar() -> T {
        return nil
        // returning nil is now allowed
    }
}
```

The appropriate method will be invoked depending on whether T is optional or not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a nasty work around.. I throw an exception for nil return type. Then in the generic function operator I catch that specific exception and return `nil` if `T` is `NilLiteralConvertible`.. Otherwise I just execute normally..

```
class Function<T> {
    var ptr: () throws -> T

    init<Func>(block: Func, args: AnyObject...) {
        self.ptr = {() throws -> T in
            let result: AnyObject? = execute(block, args...)

            if T.self == Void.self {
                return Void() as! T
            }

            throw BlockError.BlockReturnsNil
        }
    }
}

postfix func ^ <T>(left: Function<T>) throws -> T {
    return try left.ptr()
}

postfix func ^ <T : NilLiteralConvertible>(left: Function<T>) throws -> T {
    do {
        return try left.ptr() 
    }
    catch BlockError.BlockReturnsNil {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following casts `Any?` to `T` returning `nil` only if `T` is optional and `from` is `nil`. It crashes, if `from` cannot be cast to `T`.

```
func cast<T>(from v: Any?)->T {        
    return v as! T
}

func cast<T>(from v: Any?)->T where T: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    guard let v = v else { return nil }
    return v as! T
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick as of Swift 3.1. Modification of user3763801's answer.

```
func cast<T>(_ v: Any) -> T {
    return v as! T
}
```